# Find students who take most courses SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume there's a table *students* containing student id, semester id and number of courses taken in each semester:

```
student    semester    num_courses
10001      23          3
10002      23          5
10003      23          1
10004      25          2
10005      25          3
10003      25          5
10000      26          4
10013      26          2
...
```

How can I find students in each semester who took the largest number of courses?

Expected output would be:

```
student    semester    num_courses
10002      23          5
10003      25          5
10000      26          4
...
```

I thought of using `OVER PARTITION BY`, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly with this type of query. What I got is not working as expected.

```
SELECT s.student, s.semester, MAX(s.num_courses) OVER (PARTITION BY s.semester) AS max
FROM students s;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. Now that you have the students' semester course counts along with the maximum semester course counts, compare the two:

```
SELECT semester, num_courses, student
FROM
(
  SELECT
    student,
    semester, 
    num_courses,
    MAX(num_courses) OVER (PARTITION BY semester) AS semester_max_num_courses
  FROM students s
) with_max
WHERE num_courses = semester_max_num_courses
ORDER BY semester, student;
```

Another approach would be to select all maximum semester course counts and then use this to get the students:

```
SELECT semester, num_courses, student
FROM students
WHERE (semester, num_courses) IN
(
  SELECT semester, MAX(num_courses)
  from students
  GROUP BY semester
)
ORDER BY semester, student;
```

Answer (score 0):

With row_number() you can easily have a serial number in descending order of num_courses. Then just pick the rows with first serial number for each semister.

Subquery:

```
select student ,semester, num_courses from 
(
Select student ,semester, num_courses, row_number()over(partition by semester 
order by num_courses desc)rn from students 
)t
where rn=1
```

Common table expression

```
With cte as
(
Select student ,semester, num_courses, row_number()over(partition by semester 
order by num_courses desc)rn from students 
)
select student ,semester, num_courses from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, also if more than one student has max number of courses

```
WITH cte as 
( 
 SELECT s.semester, MAX(s.num_courses) as num
 FROM students s
 GROUP BY s.semester 
)
SELECT s.student, s.semester, s.num_courses FROM students s JOIN cte on s.semester = 
cte.semester
WHERE cte.num = s.course
ORDER BY s.semester
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per semester, then in Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (semester) s.*
from students s
order by semester, num_courses desc;
```

If you want *all* students who have the maximum number, then Thorsten's answer is appropriate.